# How do i replace Quick Launch in SharePoint 2013 with my custom HTML code?

Tags: 2013, launch

I have created a custom HTML/CSS accordion from the requirements of the site.
Now i want to use my html/accordion on all sites, both current and future as default menu.

How can i make it so?
I am site Admin, but this is a SharePoint 2013 Foundation solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply CSS on Left Navigation in MasterPage. You can [Create an accordion-style SharePoint Quick Launch menu with jQuery](http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2009/01/16/Creating-an-accordion-style-SharePoint-Quick-Launch-menu-with-jQuery.aspx) :-

```
$(function(){
 /*set dynamic css logic*/
 if($('#sideNavBox .menu-item.selected').length){
  //propagates the selected class, up the three.
  $('li.static').removeClass('selected');
  $('#sideNavBox .menu-item.selected').parents('li.static').addClass('selected');

  //collapses top siblings of selected branch
  $('#sideNavBox .menu-item.selected').parents('li.static').last().siblings()
   .find('> ul').hide();
 }
 else $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.static > ul').hide();

 /*set accordion effect*/
 $('#sideNavBox .root.static > li.static').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('ul').length){
   $(this).addClass('father').click(function(){
    if($(this).children('ul').css('display') != 'none'){
     $(this).removeClass('selected').children('ul').slideUp();
    }
    else {
     /*collapse-siblings*/
     $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected').children('ul').slideUp();

     /*expand*/
     $(this).addClass('selected').children('ul').slideDown();
    }

    return false; //**<= add this one**
   });
  }
 });
});
```

Ref:

- [jQuery accordion for the Quick Launch in SP2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61808/jquery-accordion-for-the-quick-launch-in-sp2013)
- [Accordion "Left Navigation" (Quick Launch) for SharePoint 2013](http://borderingdotnet.blogspot.in/2013/04/accordion-left-navigation-for.html)