# Is it possible in SharePoint 2013 to have drop down menus on the side navigation bar AND top nav bar?

Tags: navigation, dropdown

[image]

I am wanting to make my side navigation have a dropdown instead of just indentation. Is that possible?

Comment: A similar question was asked earlier to which you can refer, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/61808/40602

Comment: Or you can also use this ready made script. Its output is simple and feels more like SharePoint UI. http://yakovenkomax.com/converting-sharepoint-2013-quick-launch-to-accordion-menu/

Answer (score 1):

On the left Navigation Bar you can't have a drop down effect but on Top level navigation you will get a drop down menu effect by default when add a Heading and add links under that heading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, Top Navigation bar automatically has dropdown(menu/submenu like html). Do you see any issue here ? For current navigation/quick launch or left navigation we can use REST API.

Use below REST API to get required Navigation items for Global and Current navigation and generate custom html structure to get required dropdown menu.

```
GET http://server/_api/navigation/menustate?mapprovidername='GlobalNavigationSwitchableProvider'


GET http://server/_api/navigation/menustate?mapprovidername='CurrentNavigationSwitchableProvider'
```